# Shell script to create directory from any random directory

Tags: shell

I am currently in /Desktop on my ubuntu system and I want to create a directory named vip inside /Documents/subd. Please not that Documents and Desktop are at same level. But the crux of this question is that I have to write a shell script such that it can create the requied directory from any directory of the system, no matter where it is situated.
I have tried concatenating $home with the required directory path!! But it is not working.

> mkdir $home."/Documents/subd/vip"

I need to run this inside /Desktop or any other directory.
Please guide me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```sh
mkdir "$HOME/Documents/subd/vip"
```

You just had some minor errors in your command.